# Create string query concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table set up with the following rows:

```
Id_numbers             | Name
------------------------------------------------------- 
00001                  | Clara Sujadi 
00002                  | Raj Setamil 
00003                  | Oakley Suherman
```

I want to `concat` a value inside variable.

Here is what I've tried:

```
DECLARE @query      VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT CONCAT(Id_numbers, Name, "some-text") FROM table_name'

EXEC @query
```

this always gives me error:

> Invalid column name 'some-text'.

How to create a query `concat` inside a variable?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct delimiter for a string in SQL uses single quotes.  You can double them to include them in a string:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @query = 'SELECT CONCAT(Id_numbers, Name, ''some-text'') FROM table_name'

EXEC @query
```